# IsDouble check for string in Vb.net?

Tags: .net, vb.net, string

I will get data in `DataTable`. I am going to iterate data in `foreach`. I will have all types of data in `Datatable`. Now I need to find `Double` for each item (`string`) in `DataTable`. How to find `IsDouble` for string?

Ex:

I have `"21342.2121"` string. I need to covert this to `Double`. But sometimes the data will be `"TextString"`. So I can't use `Double.Parse()`.

How to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the wrong approach, you'll need to know up front what each column in the data table represents.  Run this program to see what can go wrong:

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim value As Double
        If Double.TryParse("1e0", value) Then
            Console.WriteLine("Uh-oh")
        End If
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: Assuming "Uh-oh" means that the conversion was done successfully! :-)

Comment: To "Infinity" and beyond "NaN"!

Answer (score 7):

```
Dim val as Double
Double.TryParse("MyString", val)
Double.TryParse("1234.567", val)
```

First TryParse() will return false. Second TryParse() will return true and place 1234.567 into `val`.

Answer (score 6):

Try [`Double.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1.aspx). This will return false if the number is not in a valid/recognized format, allowing you to do whatever you need to do in this scenario.

Comment: Yes, Double.TryParse should help James123.

Answer (score 5):

Just to expand on the (correct) answers already provided, here's a complete code example of how to use `Double.TryParse`:

```
Dim value As Double
If Double.TryParse(stringFromDataTable, value) Then
    ' text has been parsed as value, '
    ' so you can use value however you see fit '
Else
    ' text was not a valid double, so you can '
    ' notify the user or do whatever you want... '
    ' note that value will be zero in this case '
End If
```

Answer (score 2):

May I ask why your storing doubles as strings and mixing them with non numeric string values? It seems to be like you would want to avoid doing that all costs.

Comment: The OP may not have control over the source of data. For example, I ran across this question because I'm working on some code to load user created shapefiles. We have restrictions on the allowed data, but users have requested less stringent requirements on the data types of each column. For some reason, it is simpler for some users to generate the shapefiles with string datatypes instead of the correct ones.